# How to read JSON file with number of key in nested dictionary keeps changing

Tags: python, sql, json, dictionary, parsing

I have this JSON nested dictionary I need to parse into SQL table. The problem is the number of key `tank` (max is 4) in nested dictionary keeps changing with different `site_id`. Are there a way to read them?

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "site_id": 30183,
            "city": "Seattle",
            "state": "US-WA",
            "tank": [
                {
                    "id": 00001,
                    "name": "Diesel"
                },
                {
                    "id": 00002,
                    "name": "Diesel"
                },
                {
                    "id": 00003,
                    "name": "Unleaded 89"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "site_id": 200942,
            "city": "Boise",
            "state": "ID-WA",
            "tank": [
                {
                    "id": 00001,
                    "name": "Diesel"
                },
                {
                    "id": 00002,
                    "name": "Unleaded 95"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my current code:

```
for site in response['data']:
    row = []
    row.extend([site['site_id'], site['city'], site['state']])
    for tank in site['tank']:
        row.extend([tank['id'], tank['name']])
```

Any `site_id` that does not have enough 4 `tank` can have missing value replaced with `NULL`

I don't know how to modify it to adjust to different number of `tank` keys. Any suggestion help! Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of your current output, and what you would like your output to be, please.

Comment: I'm trying to insert contain of ```row``` into a SQL table. Current output is an error message ```The SQL contains 11 parameter markers, but 9 parameters were supplied```

Comment: You should edit that in to your original question. Consider inserting `None` or `null` for the blank tank parameters.